# Node.js sftp download file

Tags: javascript, node.js, sftp

I am using Node.js to pull files from a remote server. I want to be able to download theses files anytime I pull put the file path. I have tried:

Connection and pull file

```
var Client = require('ssh2-sftp-client');
var sftp = new Client();

var remotePathToList = '/archiveFiles/file.wav';

sftp.connect({
    host: '*******',
    port: '22',
    username: '******',
    password: '******'
}).then(() => {
   res.download(remotePathToList);
}).catch((err) => {
   console.log(err, 'catch error');
```

But I get a "ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat "C:'/archiveFiles/file.wav'". But I am trying to download theses files from the remote server not my local desktop.

Comment: Are you sure the host is a proper hostname or an ip, Because it defaults to localhost otherwise.

Comment: Yes, I made sure to test the connection by listing the directory. But I am not sure if using `res.download` is the right way to go for this.

Comment: I just saw the docs, should it not be `sftp.get(remoteFilePath, [useCompression], [encoding]);` From [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ssh2-sftp-client#get)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the documentation for the library you're using [ssh2-sftp-client](https://github.com/jyu213/ssh2-sftp-client).  There's a `get` method for retrieving files and an example [here](https://github.com/jyu213/ssh2-sftp-client/blob/master/example/demo.js#L36).

Here's an example of how it may look for you.

```
sftp.connect(config).then(() => {  
  sftp.get('/archiveFiles/file.wav').then((data) => {
    var outFile = fs.createWriteStream('file.wav')
    data.on('data',function(response) {
      outFile.write(response);
    });
    data.on('close', function() {
      outFile.close();
    });
  });
})
```

Comment: I got it to work thanks! But i get this warning (node:1656) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): TypeError: sftp.get(...).pipe is not a function

Comment: @carlosE. looks like `get` resolves as a promise, I updated the code above.

Comment: For some reason when the file gets downloaded and I try to play it, I get a  "Windows Media Player cannot play the file. The Player might not support the file type or might not support the codec that was used to compress the file.". Even though the file is playable before hand when it was stored.

Comment: @carlosE. what is the solution for this. I am facing the same issue.